# Swapping wireless antennas in Laptop?

Tags: wireless-networking, laptop, 3g, gps, minipci

I have two mPCIe slots in my laptop which have their own set of antennas:

- Slot A (full-size only), 3G/GPS card
- Slot B (half-size only), WiFi/Bluetooth card.

I'm planning to replace them with new parts as follwing:

- Slot A, new WiFi card (full-size)
- Slot B, new 3G/GPS card (half-size)

The question is: Is there any performance, compatility or range issues because of antennas swapping ?

To be more precise, does Slot A antennas' may be solely designed for 3G/GPS and Slot B antennas' only for WiFi ?

Comment: why don't you just put the new wifi card in slot B and the new 3G card in slot A like it was in the first place?

Comment: My bad, the new WiFi card is full-size and the new 3G/GPS is now half-size